# How to isolate certain rows in a column from a csv in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv, finance

I am very new to coding and could use some help. I download a csv (attached screenshot) from CBOE's website using the below code:

```
import csv, urllib.request

weeklys_url = 'https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(weeklys_url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
weeklys = csv.reader(lines)

for row in weeklys:
    print(row)
```

I then need to isolate only the ticker symbols in the first column and starting at the 16th row (AMPL, ARKF, ARKG, etc.). The first 14 rows I do not need. The big issue is that this CSV is subject to change (rows may not be the same in the future), but I will need to continue isolating just those ticker symbols in that first column. Any ideas/help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
[csv screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQfOf.png)

Comment: Instead of the screenshot, post the CSV file itself as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the header of that section, delete everything up to that point, and build the csv from there. Include some error detection in case the author figures out how to spell "weeklies" correctly.

```
import csv, urllib.request

weeklys_url = 'https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(weeklys_url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    if line.startswith("Available weeklys"):
        del lines[:i]
        break
    else:
        print("Error: Did not see csv marker 'Available weeklys'")
        exit(2)

weeklys = csv.reader(lines)

for row in weeklys:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I am getting the Error message every time.